# How to change a global defined variable from a function in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I am passing a structure as a variable to a function, this function accepts a structure argument.

and then i am changing some of values of the passed structure inside the function and i want to change the global variable defined under the same name.

```
struct Neuron{

double Center[3];
char name;
int xCor;
int yCor;

};

struct Neuron Q;
struct Neuron W;
struct Neuron E;
struct Neuron R;


void Winning_NEURON(struct Neuron K){
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

   K.Center[i] =  K.Center[i]+(learningParam*(inputArray[i]-K.Center[i]));
}
```

So if i pass neuron Q to the function, the data is computed correctly but the Q neuron values does not change, how can i change globally and not only locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of type `struct Neuron` is passed by value, meaning the function receives a *copy* of the structure, leaving the original unchanged. To pass by reference, make the argument a pointer (`struct Neuron *`) and pass the address of your original, e.g., `&Q`.

Comment: Even though your `struct Neuron` contains an array, it is still passed by value. C arrays *do* get passed by value (effectively) if they are embedded in a struct that is being passed by value.  That's a C trick for simulating by-value passing semantics for arrays. Instead of trying to pass `int array[42]`, make a `struct array_wrapper { int array[42]; }` and pass that structure.